# insert blank line before matching pattern in multiple files using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

Requirement is to insert a blank line in multiple files before the matching pattern line

Consider a file with below contents
Apple
Tree
orange
[Fruit]
Red
Green

Expected output:
Apple
Tree
orange

[Fruit]
Red
Green

Tried below code. Help me to figure out the mistake in below code

```
$FileName = Get-ChildItem -Filter *.ini -Recurse
$Pattern = "\[Fruit]\"
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$file = Get-Content $FileName
$insert = @()

for ($i=0; $i -lt $file.count; $i++) {
  if ($file[$i] -match $pattern) {
    $insert += $i #Record the position of the line before this one
  }
}

#Now loop the recorded array positions and insert the new text
$insert | Sort-Object -Descending | ForEach-Object { $file.insert($_," ") }

Set-Content $FileName $file
```

above code owrks fine for single file but for multiple file, the contents of the file are repeated

Comment: regexr.com - I'd suggest learning what comparison operators are first.

Comment: There is a lot going on here; best not to change your original question too much as it makes many of the comments and answers below meaningless. I have separated out your first attempt and second attempts.

Answer (score 1):

Re: how to make this work for multiple files...

```
$FileName = Get-ChildItem -Filter *.ini -Recurse
```

If there is only one .ini file then **$FileName** will be a single file.

The use of the wildcard and `-Recurse` switch suggests that you are expecting to find multiple files; thus this command will assign that *collection* of files to the **$FileName** variable (i.e. it will be an array).

Notice that when you call `Get-Content` you pass **$FileName**:

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$file = Get-Content $FileName
```

This won't work when **$FileName** is a collection/array of files.

What you need to do is put a loop in place that will perform your "insert a line break" logic **foreach** (hint hint) of the files in the array. NOW go and look at those PS tutorials again...

Answer (score 0):

[Regex character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcharclass.html)

Try to take the time to learn regex properly

```
$Pattern = "\[Fruit\]"
```

Comment: $FileName = "C:\Users\Desktop\working2\*.ini"
$Pattern = "[\Fruit\]"
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$file = Get-Content $FileName
$insert = @()

for ($i=0; $i -lt $file.count; $i++) {
  if ($file[$i] -match $pattern) {
    $insert += $i #Record the position of the line before this one
  }
}

#Now loop the recorded array positions and insert the new text
$insert | Sort-Object -Descending | ForEach-Object { $file.insert($_," ") }

Set-Content $FileName $file
above code works fine for single file but when executed for multiple files, the contents of each file are repeated

Comment: Please take a little time to learn the basics of Powershell. This MVA course is free of charge and gives you a good overview how to start with Powershell

[Getting Started with Microsoft PowerShell](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-us/training-courses/getting-started-with-microsoft-powershell-8276)

Comment: i tried multiple times but i am able to perform for single file but multiple files doesnot work